# Display Gwt SuggestBox cells side by side

Tags: html, css, gwt, html-table, suggestbox

GWT SuggestBox's search results are displayed in a `<table>` element, which (obviously) contains one `<td>` element per result. This causes the results to display **on top of each other**, like that:

[image]

Instead, I wish I could display the results **side-by-side**. Since the results are comprised within `<td>` elements, I wonder how I could possibly make each `<td>` to inline itself.

It would be neat to show the search results in a sort of grid (think of StackOverflow's tag suggestion widget, when you compose a question):

[image]

instead of a boring top-down list.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you describe is the `DefaultSuggestionDisplay` (which uses a `Menu` widget with one `MenuItem` per suggestion), but you're free to implement a [`SuggestionDisplay`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/SuggestBox.SuggestionDisplay.html) the way you want.

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know the existence of this possibility.